# Disabling PyQt5 window shadow

Tags: python, pyqt5

There is a very annoying kind of shadow/frame over my PyQt5 window. The window is made as a custom class:

```py
class CustomWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomWindow,self).__init__()
        self.bg = '#FFFFFF'
        self.opacity =1 

    def paintEvent(self, event=None):
        painter = QPainter(self)

        painter.setOpacity(self.opacity)
        painter.setBrush(QColor(self.bg))
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(0,0,0)))   
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())

    def config(self, bg, op):
        self.bg = bg
        self.opacity = op
```

The shadow thing I'm talking about:

[image]

You can see that there are thin black lines on the left and upper edges of the window. Does anyone know how to disable them?

Comment: You're drawing it. `0, 0, 0` is black in rgb. Change to `painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Musicmante's solution worked:

> You're drawing it. 0, 0, 0 is black in rgb. Change to painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)